# Populate a field after two other fields have been filled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to populate a field (with JavaScript not jquery) after two other form fields have been populated. At the moment, I'm doing it via a blur event listener on the second field; however, it's a bit of a hack because the user may not fill the forms in in order. I also need to perform some processing on the resultant value (concatenating the strings and replacing spaces with dashes).

I can't think logically how the best way to do this is. The only way I can think of is an event handler that fires after both fields have been filled (or blurred), but can't find any information around this. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Show us an example of the form, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, also use a blur on the other one. In pseudo code:

```
$('input.field1, input.field2').on('blur', function() {
     if(field1 == filled && field2 == filled) {
         doMagic();
     } else {
         goBackToBed();
     }
}
```

Or in human language: build a function that gets called every time one of the two input fields are blurred. Then check if BOTH fields have content. If they do, do whatever you want to do, if they don't, just wait till the next blur event.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @giorgio did, I have modified answer for **pure javascript way**, You can also use event driven approach like below.

HTML:

```
<section>
    A:<input type="text" id="a" />
    B:<input type="text" id="b" />
    C:<input type="text" id="c" />
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
        var myevent = new Event('inputFilled');
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = document.getElementById("b");
        var c = document.getElementById("c");

        a.addEventListener('inputFilled', function (e) {
            //do your code here
            c.value = "A is filled last";
        });

        b.addEventListener('inputFilled', function (e) {
            // do you code here
            c.value = "B is filled last";
        });

        a.onblur = function () {
            var textA = this.value;
            var textB = b.value;
            if (textA && textB) {
                a.dispatchEvent(myevent);
            }
        };

        b.onblur = function () {
            var textB = this.value;
            var textA = a.value;
            if (textA && textB) {
                b.dispatchEvent(myevent);
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Which results, your desired code only will executed only if both inputs are filled.